# Take and save an image in ycbcr format using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

We have a Matlab program that takes images from a camera in YCbCr format and then saves like an RGB image with the R values being the Y values of the image, the G values being the Cb values of the image, and the B values being the Cr values of the image. Is there a way to replicate this process in C++ openCV?

Comment: You mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided OpenCV can [read](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) the image from the camera, yes, you can replicate this process in OpenCV. All you have to do is make sure each channel is within the acceptable range (0..255 for 8 bit) and [save](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite) the image to the file.

Regarding ranges of the values, Cb and Cr can be negative, but G and B may not. You can get around that by either [shifting](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#convertscale) - adding 128 to Cb and Cr when saving (and do the opposite when loading) - or by being clever about which channels are signed and unsigned.

Regarding saving, the image saving code assumes the image is RGB, and encodes the R, G, B components as-is. If your image is YCbCr, then Y would be encoded as R, Cb as G and Cr as B. The image would look wrong opened in other programs, but that's expected.