# Problem during converting RGB to YIQ color mode and vice versa in uint8

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a matrix that is an image with BGR value in it. here's the image that have been sliced to make it shorter in the question

```py
img = [[[72, 63,  0],
        [71, 62,  0],
        [70, 61,  0]],

       [[73, 64,  1],
        [71, 62,  0],
        [70, 61,  0]],

       [[73, 64,  1],
        [72, 63,  0],
        [71, 62,  0]],

       [[73, 64,  1],
        [72, 63,  0],
        [71, 62,  0]],

       [[74, 65,  2],
        [72, 63,  0],
        [71, 62,  0]]]
```

i have succeded to make a function that convert the BGR value to YIQ, but this function didn't convert the YIQ value to uint8. it leaves the I and Q value able to be negative value

```py
import numpy as np

def RGB2YIQ(img):
    BGR = img.copy().astype(float)
    R = BGR[:,:,2]
    G = BGR[:,:,1]
    B = BGR[:,:,0]

    Y = (0.299 * R) + (0.587 * G) + (0.114 * B)
    I = (0.59590059 * R) + (-0.27455667 * G) + (-0.32134392 * B)
    Q = (0.21153661 * R) + (-0.52273617 * G) + (0.31119955 * B)

    YIQ = (np.dstack((Y,I,Q))).astype(int)

    return YIQ

>>> RGB2YIQ(img)
>>> array([[[ 45, -40, -10],
            [ 44, -39, -10],
            [ 43, -39, -10]],

           [[ 46, -40, -10],
            [ 44, -39, -10],
            [ 43, -39, -10]],

           [[ 46, -40, -10],
            [ 45, -40, -10],
            [ 44, -39, -10]],

           [[ 46, -40, -10],
            [ 45, -40, -10],
            [ 44, -39, -10]],

           [[ 47, -40, -10],
            [ 45, -40, -10],
            [ 44, -39, -10]]])
```

i also have made the conversion back to RGB which also working fine

```py
def YIQ2RGB(img):
    YIQ = img.copy().astype(int)
    Y = YIQ[:,:,0]
    I = YIQ[:,:,1]
    Q = YIQ[:,:,2]

    R = (1 * Y) + (0.95598634 * I) + (0.6208248 * Q)
    G = (1 * Y) + (-0.27201283 * I)) + (-0.64720424 * Q)
    B = (1 * Y) + (-1.10674021 * I) + (1.70423049 * Q)

    RGB = (np.dstack((R,G,B))).astype(np.uint8)

    return RGB

>>>YIQ2RGB(img)
>>>array([[[ 0, 62, 72],
           [ 0, 61, 70],
           [ 0, 60, 69]],

          [[ 1, 63, 73],
           [ 0, 61, 70],
           [ 0, 60, 69]],
 
          [[ 1, 63, 73],
           [ 0, 62, 72],
           [ 0, 61, 70]],

          [[ 1, 63, 73],
           [ 0, 62, 72],
           [ 0, 61, 70]],

          [[ 2, 64, 74],
           [ 0, 62, 72],
           [ 0, 61, 70]]], dtype=uint8)
```

the problem happens when i tried to make the YIQ array to uint8 type and then convert it back to RGB. i tried to add 128 into the I and Q channel, so i modified the RGB2YIQ function to return an uint8 types array

```py
import numpy as np

def RGB2YIQ(img):
    BGR = img.copy().astype(float)
    R = BGR[:,:,2]
    G = BGR[:,:,1]
    B = BGR[:,:,0]

    Y = (0.299 * R) + (0.587 * G) + (0.114 * B)
    I = (0.59590059 * R) + (-0.27455667 * G) + (-0.32134392 * B)
    Q = (0.21153661 * R) + (-0.52273617 * G) + (0.31119955 * B)

    YIQ = (np.dstack((Y,I + 128,Q + 128))).astype(np.uint8)

    return YIQ

>>> RGB2YIQ(img)
>>> array([[[ 45,  87, 117],
            [ 44,  88, 117],
            [ 43,  88, 117]],

           [[ 46,  87, 117],
            [ 44,  88, 117],
            [ 43,  88, 117]],

           [[ 46,  87, 117],
            [ 45,  87, 117],
            [ 44,  88, 117]],

           [[ 46,  87, 117],
            [ 45,  87, 117],
            [ 44,  88, 117]],

           [[ 47,  87, 117],
            [ 45,  87, 117],
            [ 44,  88, 117]]], dtype=uint8)
```

but when i modified the YIQ2RGB function and tried it, it gives me different Y values, which was weird, since the only thing i changed was adding 128 and subtracting it back yet it give me different value for only one channel.

```py
def YIQ2RGB(img):
    YIQ = img.copy().astype(int)
    Y = YIQ[:,:,0]
    I = YIQ[:,:,1] - 128
    Q = YIQ[:,:,2] - 128

    R = (1 * Y) + (0.95598634 * I) + (0.6208248 * Q)
    G = (1 * Y) + (-0.27201283 * I) + (-0.64720424 * Q)
    B = (1 * Y) + (-1.10674021 * I) + (1.70423049 * Q)

    RGB = (np.dstack((R,G,B))).astype(np.uint8)

    return RGB

>>>YIQ2RGB(img)
>>>array([[[255,  63,  71],
           [255,  61,  69],
           [254,  60,  68]],

          [[  0,  64,  72],
           [255,  61,  69],
           [254,  60,  68]],

          [[  0,  64,  72],
           [255,  63,  71],
           [255,  61,  69]],

          [[  0,  64,  72],
           [255,  63,  71],
           [255,  61,  69]],

          [[  0,  65,  73],
           [255,  63,  71],
           [255,  61,  69]]], dtype=uint8)
```

i suspect it was because the type casting problem but i've went back and forth between np.uint8
and int, and still giving me the same result

Comment: Why do you think that negative I and Q values are wrong?

Comment: it's not wrong and it is the right value, but i wanted to saved it as an image so i make it within uint8 range. here's a post i follow about making it uint8 https://stackoverflow.com/a/22367513/12120197

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is just an illusive bug...

The following code lines:

```
R = BGR[:,:,2]
G = BGR[:,:,1]
B = BGR[:,:,0]
```

It should be:

```
R = BGR[:,:,0]
G = BGR[:,:,1]
B = BGR[:,:,2]
```

---

Other issues:

- You need to clip the range of `RGB` to [0, 255], before casting to `uint8`.
- For better accuracy, you may use `np.round` before casting from `float` to integer.

---

Here is a slightly modified version of your code:

```
import numpy as np

def RGB2YIQ(img):
    BGR = img.copy().astype(float)
    R = BGR[:,:,0]
    G = BGR[:,:,1]
    B = BGR[:,:,2]

    Y = (0.299 * R) + (0.587 * G) + (0.114 * B)
    I = (0.59590059 * R) + (-0.27455667 * G) + (-0.32134392 * B)
    Q = (0.21153661 * R) + (-0.52273617 * G) + (0.31119955 * B)

    YIQ = np.round(np.dstack((Y,I + 128,Q + 128))).astype(np.uint8)

    return YIQ


def YIQ2RGB(img):
    YIQ = img.copy().astype(float)
    Y = YIQ[:,:,0]
    I = YIQ[:,:,1] - 128
    Q = YIQ[:,:,2] - 128

    R = (1 * Y) + (0.95598634 * I) + (0.6208248 * Q)
    G = (1 * Y) + (-0.27201283 * I) + (-0.64720424 * Q)
    B = (1 * Y) + (-1.10674021 * I) + (1.70423049 * Q)

    RGB = np.round(np.clip(np.dstack((R,G,B)), 0, 255)).astype(np.uint8)

    return RGB


img = np.array([[[72, 63,  0],
               [71, 62,  0],
               [70, 61,  0]],
       
              [[73, 64,  1],
               [71, 62,  0],
               [70, 61,  0]],
       
              [[73, 64,  1],
               [72, 63,  0],
               [71, 62,  0]],
       
              [[73, 64,  1],
               [72, 63,  0],
               [71, 62,  0]],
       
              [[74, 65,  2],
               [72, 63,  0],
               [71, 62,  0]]], np.uint8)

yiq_img = RGB2YIQ(img)

rgb_img = YIQ2RGB(yiq_img)

print(rgb_img.astype(np.int16) - img.astype(np.int16))  # Print the difference.
```

---

Result:

```
[[[1 1 0]
  [0 0 1]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 1 0]
  [0 0 1]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 1 0]
  [1 1 0]
  [0 0 1]]

 [[1 1 0]
  [1 1 0]
  [0 0 1]]

 [[1 1 0]
  [1 1 0]
  [0 0 1]]]
```

The maximum difference is 1 (not zero due to rounding).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, didn't know about np.clip before